# How to kill/finish and activity from another activity?

Tags: java, android

I have an activity with 36 buttons (6X6) like a chess board, and when I click one of them I call another class which pops up a question. Here's how (an example for first button):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){

        case R.id.ib1:

            Intent i = new Intent(Cigle.this, Pitanja_Cigle.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, B1);
            break;
```

Then, the question pops up (Pitanja_Cigle.class).

After 120 seconds the time is up, and I have another popup class (Popup_opis.class) that tells the user that the time is up and some other info, it's not relevant to this.

The problem is, when, in the last seconds of the game I click one of 36 buttons and a question pops up, and the time is up, but I did not manage to answer the question on time, the Popup_opis.class pops up, and when I click OK in it to close it, I can see that last question still opened. How to kill/finish that question activity the moment the time is up?

Here's my Popup_opis.class:

```
public class Popup_opis extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    TextView tvOpis,tvNaslov,tvBrojPoena, tvResenje;
    String primljenOpis, naslov, resenje;
    int brojPoenaPrimljeno;
    Button OK;



    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.popup_opis);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
        if(extras !=null) {
           primljenOpis = extras.getString("poslatOpis");
           brojPoenaPrimljeno = getIntent().getIntExtra("brojPoenaPrimljeno", 0);
           naslov = extras.getString("naslov");
           resenje = extras.getString("resenje");
        }

        initVariables();

    }

    private void initVariables() {


        Typeface tv = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "ARIALN.TTF");
        OK = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bOK);
        tvOpis = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvOpis);
        tvBrojPoena = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBrojPoena);
        tvBrojPoena.setTypeface(tv);
        tvNaslov = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNaslov);
        tvNaslov.setTypeface(tv);
        tvResenje = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResenje);
        tvResenje.setTypeface(tv);
        tvOpis.setTypeface(tv);
        tvOpis.setText(primljenOpis);
        tvBrojPoena.setText("Osvojili ste " + brojPoenaPrimljeno + " poena u ovoj igri.");
        tvNaslov.setText(naslov);
        tvResenje.setText(resenje);



    OK.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    }



    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

And my questions class, Pitanja_cigle.class:

```
public class Pitanja_Cigle extends Activity{

    public static String tacanOdg;
    int counter = 0;

    Button b1, b2, b3, b4;
    TextView question;
    boolean tacno = true;
    boolean pogresno = false;


LinkedList<Long> mAnsweredQuestions = new LinkedList<Long>();

    private String generateWhereClause(){
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (Long l : mAnsweredQuestions){
            result.append(" AND _ID <> " + l);
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    Runnable mLaunchTaskFinish = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            finish();
        }
     };

    private class Answer {
        public Answer(String opt, boolean correct) {
            option = opt;
            isCorrect = correct;
        }

        String option;
        boolean isCorrect;
    }
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    final OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Answer ans = (Answer) v.getTag();
            if (ans.isCorrect) {
                Intent resp = new Intent();
                resp.putExtra("score", tacno);
                setResult(1, resp);
                Intent i = new Intent("rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.TACANODGOVOR");
                startActivity(i);
                mHandler.postDelayed(mLaunchTaskFinish,1200);
            }
            else{
                Intent resp = new Intent();
                resp.putExtra("score", pogresno);
                setResult(1, resp);
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PogresanOdgovor.class);
                i.putExtra("tacanOdgovor", tacanOdg);
                startActivity(i);
                mHandler.postDelayed(mLaunchTaskFinish,2200);
            }
        }
     };


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);   //full screen
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.pitanja_cigle);

        InicirajVariable();

        nextQuestion();
    }

    private void nextQuestion() {
        counter++;

        TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(this);
        DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

        if(!myDbHelper.checkDataBase()){
        mDbHelper.createDatabase();
        }

        try{    //Pokusava da otvori db

            mDbHelper.open();  //baza otvorena

            Cursor c = mDbHelper.getPitanjaCigle(generateWhereClause());

            mAnsweredQuestions.add(c.getLong(0));

            List<Answer> labels = new ArrayList<Answer>();

            labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(2), true));
            labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(3), false));
            labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(4), false));
            labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(5), false));

            tacanOdg = c.getString(2);

            Collections.shuffle(labels);

            question.setText(c.getString(1));

            b1.setText(labels.get(0).option);
            b1.setTag(labels.get(0));
            b1.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            b2.setText(labels.get(1).option);
            b2.setTag(labels.get(1));
            b2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            b3.setText(labels.get(2).option);
            b3.setTag(labels.get(2));
            b3.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            b4.setText(labels.get(3).option);
            b4.setTag(labels.get(3));
            b4.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

    }

    finally{    // kada zavrsi sa koriscenjem baze podataka, zatvara db
        mDbHelper.close();
    }
    }

    private void InicirajVariable() {
        Typeface pitanje = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "myriad.ttf");
        Typeface dugmad = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Bebas.ttf");

        question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPitanjeCigle);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bOdgCigle1);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bOdgCigle2);
        b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bOdgCigle3);
        b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bOdgCigle4);

        b1.setTypeface(dugmad);
        b2.setTypeface(dugmad);
        b3.setTypeface(dugmad);
        b4.setTypeface(dugmad);
        question.setTypeface(pitanje);

    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
 06-07 14:16:23.631: E/AndroidRuntime(5523): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    06-07 14:16:23.631: E/AndroidRuntime(5523): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=30, result=0, data=null} to activity {rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno/rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Cigle}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    06-07 14:16:23.631: E/AndroidRuntime(5523):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.)
    06-07 14:16:23.631: E/AndroidRuntime(5523):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.)
    06-07 14:16:23.631: E/AndroidRuntime(5523):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.)
    06-07 14:16:23.631: E/AndroidRuntime(5523):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.)
    06-07 14:16:23.631: E/AndroidRuntime(5523):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    06-07 14:16:23.631: E/AndroidRuntime(5523):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.)
    06-07 14:16:23.631: E/AndroidRuntime(5523):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.)
    06-07 14:16:23.631: E/AndroidRuntime(5523):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    06-07 14:16:23.631: E/AndroidRuntime(5523):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.)
    06-07 14:16:23.631: E/AndroidRuntime(5523):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.)
    06-07 14:16:23.631: E/AndroidRuntime(5523):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.)
    06-07 14:16:23.631: E/AndroidRuntime(5523):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    06-07 14:16:23.631: E/AndroidRuntime(5523): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    06-07 14:16:23.631: E/AndroidRuntime(5523):     at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Cigle.onActivityResult(Cigle.)
    06-07 14:16:23.631: E/AndroidRuntime(5523):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.)
    06-07 14:16:23.631: E/AndroidRuntime(5523):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.)
    06-07 14:16:23.631: E/AndroidRuntime(5523):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Register a broadcast receiver for your Pitanja_cigle's class onCreate method.

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action= intent.getStringExtra("action");
        if(action.equals("close")) {
            Pitanja_cigle.this.finish();
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("Pitanja_cigle"));
}
```

Whenever you want to close it, do

```
public static void closePitanja(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("Pitanja_cigle");
    intent.putExtra("action", "close");
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Comment: I tried in my Cigle.class to do this, on timer finish, with Pitanja_Cigle.closePitanja(getApplicationContext()); but I get error Failure delivering result ResultInfo to activity

Comment: OK, so the first snippet is going in my Pitanja_cigle class and the second goes in another class, from which I want to finish Pitanja_cigle? I did this, I placed the second snippet on timer finish of my Cigle.class but I get the error from the first comment.

Comment: I think the problem is that I start the Pitanja_cigle class for result.

Comment: Is Popup_opis your pop up class? If yes you may call the closePitanja at the end of onCreate function

Comment: Yes it is. Let me try it for a second.

Comment: Nope, still the same error. After I press OK button on my popup I get force close.

Comment: Can I have a look at the stack trace? Maybe you can edit your question with the stack trace and remove it later.

Comment: What are you trying to set as activity result? I think you should set a result before calling finish() on Pitanja_cigle

Comment: Well, Pitanja_cigle is my popup question class. I am sending correct(tacno) or wrong(pogresno) back. If it's correct I add +2 points. I setResult in my OnClickListener, so when do you think I should call finish()?

Comment: You are calling finish from the popup because he failed to answer the question am i right? so I believe you should send a wrong?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31400/discussion-between-chor-waichun-and-marjanbaz)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to call `finish()` on the `Pitanja_cigle` Activity at the same time as when the OK button is pressed.

```
OK.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Pitanja_cigle.this.finish();
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I get "No enclosing instance of the type Pitanja_cigle is accessible in scope" error.